# Google check out Merchant Id Not correct

Tags: php, html

I am using google check out in my project. It is in sandbox mode.  I am using Xml api check out , When I click google button in my page , I got an error message like

```
An error had ocurred:
HTTP Status: 400:
Error message:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <error xmlns="http://checkout.google.com/schema/2" serial-number="a4ab2700-a387-4af5-9350-374049856c6e"> <error-message>No seller found with id 623746024295438</error-message> </error>
```

What is this? Actually, I have that merchant Id and Key.

Comment: why are questions that end with "Please help me urgently" such a turn off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can helpful to you

http://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70832